# Android Studio don't see some classes

Tags: android, here-api

I got example of here maps on Android.
When i try to compile this example, few classes are missing.

> com.here.android.mpa.routing.CoreRouter, com.here.android.mpa.routing.RouteWaypoint,
>   com.here.android.mpa.routing.Router,
>   com.here.android.mpa.routing.RoutingError

all these classes are missing and i can't build examples for testing.

Comment: try adding its dependency in build.gradle

Comment: These classes is out of date.

Comment: @MichaelBodnar Did you find any solution? I stuck with the same issue. HERE maps doc is also not having these classes

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that you are using the Premium Android SDK? The Starter version does not contain these classes.